# Filtering data while reading from S3 to Spark

Tags: r, hive, pyspark, amazon-emr, sparklyr

We are moving to AWS EMR/S3 and using `R` for analysis (`sparklyr` library). We have 500gb sales data in S3 containing records for multiple products. We want to analyze data for couple of products and want to read only subset of file into EMR.

So far my understanding is that `spark_read_csv` will pull in all the data. Is there a way in `R/Python/Hive` to read data only for products we are interested in?

Comment: `read_csv()` will not "pull in all the data" in the traditional sense- spark is lazy, so nothing will be done until you execute an action. Doing a read followed by a `filter()` is probably the way you want to go here.

Comment: If your dataset is **partitioned** by product -- or pdct family -- then only the "directories" matching your WHERE clause will be accessed. That's the way it works in Hadoop and anywhere else (since Oracle 8i introduced the concept 20 years ago...)

Comment: To execute read_csv shouldn't the entire data already be loaded into HDFS? I know spark_read_csv can read file from S3 and put it into hdfs. If I pipe that command to filter, will it work? So essentially - spark_read_csv(cs, sales.csv, memory = F) %>% filter(product == p1) ?



I have data in form of text files with each file containing data for a year. I am not sure how to use partitioning concept while pulling in data from S3 into EMR. Can you please clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the choice of the format is on the opposite side of the efficient spectrum.

Using data

- Partitioned by (`partitionBy` option of the `DataFrameWriter` or correct directory structure) column of interest.
- Clustered by (`bucketBy` option of the `DataFrameWriter` and persistent metastore) on the column of interest.

can help to narrow down the search to particular partitions in some cases, but if `filter(product == p1)` is highly selective, then you're likely looking at the wrong tool.

Depending on the requirements:

- A proper database.
- Data warehouse on Hadoop.

might be a better choice.

You should also consider choosing a better storage format (like Parquet).

Comment: I agree. Entire team is pretty new to this infrastructure and on further reading, we have decided to use parquet files.